# Serving static files in ASP.NET 5 MVC 6

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

My wwwroot static files aren't being resolved.

I understand that to serve static files, I need to put them in wwwroot:

[image: wwwroot static files]

`favicon.ico` resolves just fine, but `schema/v1-0.json` does not. I get the generic message:

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name
>   changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

I have the following wired up in `Startup`:

```
app.UseMiddleware<StaticFileMiddleware>(new StaticFileOptions());
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

I am using DNX beta6.  The above require beta5 packages. I cannot find anything online regarding serving static files in beta6.  I am not sure if this could be the cause of the problem.

**EDIT:**

As per Sirwan's answer, I have added the following, but the json file is still not available:

```
var options = new StaticFileOptions
{
    ContentTypeProvider =  new JsonContentTypeProvider(),
    ServeUnknownFileTypes = true,
    DefaultContentType = "application/json"
};

app.UseStaticFiles(options);
```

The `JsonContentTypeProvider` class:

```
public class JsonContentTypeProvider : FileExtensionContentTypeProvider
{
    public JsonContentTypeProvider()
    {
        Mappings.Add(".json", "application/json");
    }
}
```

I can even see the file when browsing the server:

[image]

Comment: My memory is a bit fuzzy here, but I believe either IIS or ASP.NET MVC filters the allowed static files by file extension.  If you add a .png file in that location for example, you'll probably be able to access it just fine.  You'll want to find the web.config or ASP.NET setting to specify allowed static file extensions and add .json to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using IIS, make sure you've added the correct mime-type mappings if you don't have a catch-all managed handler. Even though you don't *need* web.config for your website to work, IIS will still use that for your website.

Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe that if you have not configured IIS to use a managed handler to serve static files it will still default to `StaticFileModule` and calling `app.UseStaticFiles` doesn't actually do anything. If you run it using dnx, however, then `app.UseStaticFiles` gets used.

Just a side note, you should probably also upgrade to beta7 if you haven't already.

Comment: I think IIS is getting in the way. When I request any css file when hosted in IIS Express I get gzip compression 'for free'. If I host it using WebListener I don't get this behavior. It means the request isn't even reaching any of our middlewares. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: I don't think it "gets in the way". You just need to configure it properly if you want ASP.NET 5 to handle static files and not IIS.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    ServeUnknownFileTypes = true,
    DefaultContentType = "image/x-icon"
});
```

If you have multiple file types that are unknown to ASP.NET you can use `FileExtensionContentTypeProvider` class:

```
var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
provider.Mappings.Add(".json", "application/json");
provider.Mappings.Add(".ico", "image/x-icon");
// Serve static files.
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions { ContentTypeProvider = provider });
```

Comment: Won't this serve all static files?  How do I allow just json?

Comment: If you have multiple file types that are unknown to ASP.NET you can use `FileExtensionContentTypeProvider` class.

Comment: @davenewza I've updated my answer. hope it helps you.

Comment: Still the same problem.  Please see my edit - thanks!

Comment: Adding a content type provider fixed this for me. I did not need to set ServeUnknownFileTypes to true (i'm using webapi 2.2). Thanks