# How to a serve static site on Azure with Git (Bitbucket)?

Tags: git, azure, bitbucket, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a MVC 6 app on Azure and to host my static files I had to ftp to the server and manually put them on `/site/wwwroot`. This is a bit cumbersome when doing daily changes. 
To fix this I setup continuos deployment with Bitbucket on Azure. I created separate repo for the static site. I notice that the repo was added to `/site/repository`.

How do I serve the static files from there? I tried changing the virtual directory from `/ --> site\wwwroot` to  `/ --> site\repository` but got

> The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process

It was a bit scary. Reverting the change and restarting the server didn't work. I had to publish again from Visual Studio to somehow overwrite the configuration.

Comment: since you already setup continues deployment with Bitbucket for your site. when every there is a push to your repository, a new deployment should happen and whatever file change should be copied over automatically for you. why do you need to manually copy those file? i am not following what issue you are facing.

Comment: regarding to "/site/repository", Azure App Service clone your bitbucket repo into "/site/repository", but should have build script to copy build ouput to `wwwroot`

Comment: @XiaominWu Before I was using FTP, now I use git/bitbucket but I don't know how to serve the files.

Comment: @XiaominWu Like git hooks?

Comment: if you setup continues deployment, Azure will setup webhook for continues deployment. if your app is a sample app. can you put it on a public repository so that i can try and see if i am able to repro your issue?

Answer (score 2):

An MVC 6 application will have a wwwroot folder in the root directory (as a sibling to Controllers, Views etc)

If you put your static content in there, and ensure that you have `app.UseStaticFiles();` defined in your startup.cs your static content should deploy and run with the rest of your content.

Comment: I'd change the name of `wwwroot` to `ionic` because it was clearer and I just had to change a string in the `project.json`. I'll try to change it back so I only have 1 repo.

Answer (score 1):

as in the other thread ([Serving static files in ASP.NET 5 MVC 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32471638/serving-static-files-in-asp-net-5-mvc-6))

you will need to

1) try upgrade to use latest version of MVC 6  (https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/releases)

2) put static file under wwwroot

3) `app.UseStaticFiles`

4) if there is file that unknown to IIS, you will have to config mime-type via web.config or code e.g

```
var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
provider.Mappings.Add(".json", "application/json");
provider.Mappings.Add(".ico", "image/x-icon");
// Serve static files.
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions { ContentTypeProvider = provider });
```

Comment: Upgrade to the latest version of what?